# Inline SQL Troubles

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is my syntax, and it keeps telling me

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid object name redminnow.dbo.fullonresults.

And here is my actual syntax

```
Declare
@sql varchar(Max),@dbname varchar(max)

Set @dbname = 'redminnow.dbo.fullonresults'

set @sql = 'Select Count(*) From ' + @dbname + ' ' 
Print @sql
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: do you have the table or view named  "fullonresults" in the specified database "redminnow"?

Comment: Yes, I am running this syntax on the server that the table & database exist on.  And that is correct spelling of database & table name.

Comment: If the table and DB are right given the error is the schema right. The syntax looks ok works ok locally and on sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1d7d5/3/0

Comment: this code works. So you probably do not have the correct db or table name as Tim3880 suggested. What if you removed the first part, redminnow and just used dbo.fullonresults?

Comment: @sjramsay - oddly enough that allows it to run no error.

Comment: So that means you have an issue with your DB Name. Your DB name is called RedMinNow? So if you click "Databases" in your SQL Server, you have a DB called RedMinNow?